# What is the proper use of keyword 'this' in private class members?

Tags: c#, .net

When should the keyword 'this' be used within C# class definitions?

Is it standard to use the form "this.Method()" from within class? Or to just use "Method()"?  I have seen both, and usually go with the second choice, but I would like to learn more about this subject.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Most of the time it is redundant and can be omitted; a few exceptions:

- to call a chained constructor: `Foo() : this("bar") {}`
- to disambiguate between a local argument/variable and a field: `this.foo = foo;` etc
- to call an **extension** method on the current instance: `this.SomeMethod();` (where defined as `public static SomeMethod(this Foo foo) {...}`)
- to pass a reference to the current instance to an external method: `Helper.DoSomething(this);`

Answer (score 4):

*this* is mainly used to explicitly use a class member when the name alone would be ambiguous, as in this example:

```
public class FooBar
{
    private string Foo;
    private string Bar;

    public void DoWhatever(string Foo, string Bar)
    {
        // use *this* to indicate your class members
        this.Foo = Foo;
        this.Bar = Bar;
    }

    public void DoSomethingElse()
    {
        // Not ambiguity, no need to use *this* to indicate class members
        Debug.WriteLine(Foo + Bar);
    }
}
```

Aside from that, some people prefer to prefix internal method calls (`this.Method()´) because it makes it more obvious that you are not calling any external method, but I don't find it important.

It definitely has no effect on the resulting program being more or less efficient.

Answer (score 2):

I use 'this' when it becomes ambigious what your refering to, it having a local variable with the same/similar name to a class variable/method.

But its really a personal preference thing, just use what you feel is best.

Comment: I was tending towards not using 'this' 95% of the time.  But then I started to wonder if I was missing something.  I can always be sure to clarify things here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

always... just my 2 cents